# Асинхронно получать прогресс загрузки файла из другого потока (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net, asp.net-core, async-await

Есть WPF приложение с кнопкой загрузки файла.
При нажатии на эту кнопку обработчик кнопки вызывает асинхронно метод класса-сервиса, который некоторое время загружает этот файл во внешний ресурс.

Вопрос в следующем:
Как мне получать прогресс о загрузке файла, если загрузка происходит в другом потоке?

Сам процесс загрузки файла можно условно представить циклом с Thread.Sleep(1000) между итерациями.

Comment: Как вариант в том классе, где расположен метод загрузки, создать событие и в вашем цикле при каждой итерации(или порции загрузки) дергать это событие и передавать размер загруженной порции + полный размер. Там где вам нужно работать с прогрессом подпишитесь на это событие и при его срабатывании меняете прогресс.

Comment: [IProgress<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netcore-3.1) и [Progress<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Vasek, да предложенный вами вариант подошёл. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Предложенный вариант работы (см комментарий 2 выше) через Progress подошёл. У объекта этого класса можно подписаться на событие ProgressChanged и, соответсвенно, в теле метода-обработчика использовать получаемый прогресс.

Например:

```cs
IProgress<int> progressIndicator = new Progress<int>();

progressIndicator.ProgressChanged += (o, progress) => { button.Content = progress; };
```

или так:

```cs
IProgress<int> progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(progress => button.Content = progress);
```

ну и конечно же нужно реализовать метод где объект `progressIndicator` будет применяться и откуда он будет сообщать о прогрессе.

Вызвать можно так:

```cs
progressIndicator.Report(100);
```